# Can you explain why none is printing in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement

```
def great(a,b,c):
    if(a>b and a>c):
        print("a is greater")
    elif(b>a and b>c):
        print("b is greater")
    else:
        print("c is greater")
        a=great(12,3,1)
        print(a)
```

**Can you explain why none is printing in output?**

Comment: `great` doesnt return anything ... so `a=None`

Comment: Why do you expect anything else? Your function returns `None`, you assign `a` to the result of a call to your function and you print `a`

Comment: Because you call it recursively from the `else` block and you don't have a `return` statement, so `a` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

In python indentation matters,
Your Function Call is not Properly indented that is why it is not printing anything

```
def great(a,b,c):
    if(a>b and a>c):
        print("a is greater")
    elif(b>a and b>c):
        print("b is greater")
    else:
        print("c is greater")
a=great(12,3,1)
print(a)
```

Comment: `a=great(12,3,1)` and `print(a)` is not needed as `great(12,3,1)`  returns None, calling `great(12,3,1)` directly prints the output.

Comment: check the @Bibhav comment and edit the answer accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has a couple of issues that prevent it from working as intended. Let's go through them step by step:

1. Indentation: The last two lines of your code are indented incorrectly. They are part of the `else` block, which is not what you want. You should unindent them to be at the same level as the `if` and `elif` blocks.
2. Function call: You're trying to call the `great` function within itself, which is a form of recursion. However, you haven't defined a base case for the recursion, so it will run indefinitely, causing a stack overflow error.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
def great(a, b, c):
    if a > b and a > c:
        print("a is greater")
    elif b > a and b > c:
        print("b is greater")
    else:
        print("c is greater")

great(12, 3, 1)
```

With these corrections, the code should work as expected. When you call the `great` function with the values (12, 3, 1), it will correctly identify that "a is greater" and print that message.

Answer (score 0):

function great() does not return anything. In python, when nothing is returned in a function, a default 'None' value is returned. So when use:

a=great(12,3,1)

it returns None value. That value is assigned to a. Therefore, when you print a you get None.

Check out this link for more:

[https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#:~:text=Implicit%20return%20Statements,-A%20Python%20function&text=That%20default%20return%20value%20will%20always%20be%20None%20.&text=If%20you%20don't%20supply,None%20as%20a%20return%20value](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#:%7E:text=Implicit%20return%20Statements,-A%20Python%20function&text=That%20default%20return%20value%20will%20always%20be%20None%20.&text=If%20you%20don%27t%20supply,None%20as%20a%20return%20value).